# I try to make several divs show individually on click

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend

I have 6 divs, and each div when click will show a pop up window, now, the problem is that it is not working. Here is my code, I don't know what i am doing wrong:

```
var clickMe = document.getElementsByClassName("skill-items__item");
```

```
for (i = 0; i < clickMe.length; i++) {
    clickMe[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

        var ShowMe = this.nextElementSibling;

        for (i = 0; i < ShowMe.length; i++) {

            if (ShowMe[i].style.display === "block") {
                ShowMe[i].style.display = "none";
            } else {
                ShowMe.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: post your html too

Comment: Code you post a jsfiddle or something of the like with your code. This will make it a lot easier to understand how you're going at this.

Comment: Your problem is that you're using `i` twice. Your second for loop is overwriting the `i` variable from the first for loop.

Comment: here it is in Codepen : https://codepen.io/bohorquez866/pen/abOXZqb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `i` twice. Your second `for` loop is overwriting the `i` variable from the first `for` loop.

Don't worry, we've all been there. Good luck!

Comment: how come? the ones inside the fuction?

Comment: You're overwriting the incrementing variable. You're setting `i` with the first `for` loop, and then overwriting it with the second one. You need to change the inside incrementer to, say, `j`, so then it won't overwrite.